# MySQL all select rows in range

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help retrieving data from rows in range.
Let's say this is my table:

[image]

That's what I need:

I need to sort the rows by ID and then get **9** rows, where the **gameID** is *1* and *winner's* **unique_id** must be in the middle.
For example:

```
$gameID = 1;
$winner = "iii";
```

so it should return:

```
5.eee
6.fff
7.ggg
8.hhh
9.iii <--- winner in the middle
10.jjj
11.kkk
12.lll
13.mmm
```

How can I achieve this result?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
$b = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE gameID = 1 AND unique_id = 'iii'");
$res = $b->fetch();
$winnerID = $res['ID'];
$b2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE ID BETWEEN $winnerID-4 AND $winnerID+4 ORDER BY ID ASC");
$data = $b2->fetchAll();
```

This works, but I was wondering if it's possible in a single row.

Comment: what have you done to try and accomplish this yourself? We are not here to do your job for you. You show what you've attempted, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: What is ur logic? `get 9 rows`? randomly?

Comment: @Shank yes I need exactly 9 rows.

Comment: @MarcB, I will update my question in a sec.

Comment: @Nedas, so according to you, 9 rows will be selected at random and whichever row is in the middle(5th row) will be selected

Comment: @coder I need to select all 9 rows, winner one being in the middle.

Comment: but random 9 consecutive rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

It first finds the id of the winner, then selects rows with IDs smaller and greater than 4. (4 + 4 + 1 = 9)

```
SELECT * 
FROM rows 
WHERE id BETWEEN 
    (SELECT @id := id FROM rows WHERE unique_id = "iii") - 4 AND @id + 4
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cd57/2)